# Opensocial + hi5 api

Tags: .net, asp.net, opensocial

I'm trying to make an application in asp.net, which will grab all my friends from hi5 to my application using OpenSocial..

What are steps I should go through?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get started by grabbing the .Net client libraries from here: http://code.google.com/p/opensocial-net-client/

The package should have a sample app or two to get you started.

Look at the Hi5 specific links here: http://wiki.opensocial.org/index.php?title=REST_and_RPC_implementations#hi5 - you'll need them to have your application properly authenticate to get access to the data Hi5 has.

Comment: i've tried all those things..

but output is like i can get the information

not able to set the status or upload videos..

so halfway is really disappointed..!